# Updating programmatically added controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a custom control which I add a number of to a flowlayoutpanel:

```
Dim drive As New WindowsControlLibrary1.UserControl1()
drive.FileSystemlable = reader.GetString(2)
drive.AbalableSpaceLable = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(4) / 1024)
drive.TotalSpaceLable = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(5) / 1024)
drive.SetVolumeLable = reader.GetString(3)
Dim usedspace As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(5)) - Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(4))
drive.BarValue = usedspace / 1024

Form1.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(drive)
```

How can I now update these controls instead of clearing them and re-adding them all again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving your controls unique names:

```
Dim drive As New WindowsControlLibrary1.UserControl1()
drive.Name = "drive1"
```

then you can just reference them in the panel's control collection by name:

```
With DirectCast(Form1.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls("drive1"), WindowsControlLibrary1.UserControl1)
  .BarValue = 50
End With
```